# Unable to view files in SSH Session

Tags: windows, ubuntu, ssh, putty

I have 2 Ubuntu servers, both on Ubuntu 16.04. When I connect to Server1 from my Windows 10 laptop (clean install) and open VIM, NANO, or use CAT to open a file, the SSH client "freezes" (in that the session shows a partial screen, e.g. in the case of simply opening VIM, I just get "c" in the top corner and nothing else). Opening existing files results in the same freeze. The SSH client itself does NOT freeze.

Server2 however does not have this issue.

SSH Clients used: Bitvise (Win32), PuTTy (Win32), and Remote Terminal (UWP) - the behaviour seen on Server1 occurs in all 3 of these clients. 
Any idea what is going on?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VDm5S.png)

Answer (score 0):

Symptoms look like problem with large transfer. Try something like `ls -l /usr/bin`  it can hung also.

Possible cause is low intermediate MTU like described [here](https://heitorlessa.com/troubleshooting-ssh-connectivity-issues-9634b8ffff7b)

```
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS
--set-mss 1460
```

MSS possibly mist be lover down to 1300 - 1200

**UPD.**

Which is Your network topology? Servers accessible over Internet or over LAN ?

Comment: Server2 is accessible over the Internet for SSH, Server1 runs DNS, email, and HTTP services so SSH is limited to just the LAN.

Running `ls -l /usr/bin` did hang the session.

Running the iptables command as described with the MSS set to 1200 did not resolve the issue

Answer (score 0):

I need to thank @mmv-ru for pointing me in the right direction. As it turns out the other Windows machines on the network did not have this issue with Server1. After speaking with a family member who advised he had set his network adapters to an MTU of 1438, I set the WiFi adapter to the same MTU and VOILA! Issue resolved for Server1. I can now view/edit files and TOP as expected.

For those with the same issue, I used netsh to resolve:
`netsh interface ipv4 show subinterfaces` - Display MTU and Names of available connections
`netsh interface ipv4 set interface "WiFi" mtu=1438 store=persistent` - Set and save the MTU for the WiFi connection.